# Connect to docker mysql through Sequel Pro mac

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm trying to connect to my running Docker SQL database on my machine through Sequel Pro, unfortunately appears that connecting to it is failing/isn't possible through this method?

My `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```yml
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: user
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: brand
    container_name: brand-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - brand

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: brand-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - brand

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: brand-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - brand

networks:
  brand:
    driver: bridge
```

And I'm trying to connect using:

127.0.0.1
root
root
port 3306

which appears to fail... not sure how to connect

I've got `docker-compose up` running, and my containers are all running

Comment: Check if you're running mysql in your mac also. if yes, that could be binding to 3306 port and your mysql running in docker might be failing to launch.
Use `docker-compose logs -f db` to check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this question too.
the why of dealing with this problem is to change your database_host to the name you had given in `docker-compose.yml`

for example:

```
this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db' || '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123',
    database: 'CHIRINOS',
    port: 3306
});
```

here `db` in host is your database name of docker container

Answer (score 1):

This solution fixed the issue for me.

> Looks like Sail uses MySQL 8 by default, which means that you won't be able to use Sequel Pro with Sail. You can try using nightly builds or try Sequel Ace - Sequel Pro's fork.

[This is the source of the solution](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3767#issuecomment-778870148)